# Trouble installing rgbdslam_freiburg

Tags: ros, rosdep-install, ros-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is an easy one but I'm very new to ros and am having a bit of trouble. I'm trying to install [rgbdslam for rosdep](http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam).

The trouble starts here:

```
~/rosbuild_ws$ rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query Missing resource rgbdslam_freiburg
```

So I check to make sure I downloaded the code to the right place with:

```
~/rosbuild_ws$ printenv | grep ROS

ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/jade/share/ros 
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/jade/share:/opt/ros/jade/stacks 
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311     
ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/jackson/rosbuild_ws 
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES= 
ROS_DISTRO=jade 
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/jade/etc/ros
```

Here is the contents of `/home/jackson/rosbuild_ws`

```
~/rosbuild_ws$ ls -la
total 32
drwxrwxr-x  3 jackson jackson 4096 Jan 15 17:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 jackson jackson 4096 Jan 15 17:43 ..
drwxrwxr-x  4 jackson jackson 4096 Jan 15 17:44 rgbdslam_freiburg
-rw-rw-r--  1 jackson jackson  290 Jan 15 17:42 .rosinstall
-rw-rw-r--  1 jackson jackson 1697 Jan 15 17:42 setup.bash
-rw-rw-r--  1 jackson jackson 6756 Jan 15 17:42 setup.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 jackson jackson 1474 Jan 15 17:42 setup.zsh
```

I've also tried moving the directory `rgbdslam_freiburg` to `/opt/ros/jade/share` and `/opt/ros/jade/share/ros` with no success.

What else do I need to be doing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224265/trouble-installing-rgbdslam_freiburg/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 instead of 14.04 performed the [RGB-D SLAM for "Not-yet" ROS Users](http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam) (it's at the bottom of the page)

NOTE you have to make sure you have [ros mirrors](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation/UbuntuMirrors) setup or you won't be able to set everything up:

---

Originally posted by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) with karma: 396 on 2016-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0